# GXT 3 spinnerField validation

Tags: gwt, extjs, gxt

I want to validate that user cannot change spinner value manually by typing in text box of spinner.

For example a field sales multiple = x which I fetched from server not fix.
and displays a spinner field with limitation of like bellow

spinner.setMinValue = x
spinner.setIncrement = x
spinner.setValue = x

so user forcefully select a value which is multiple with x. e.g. if x=3 the user have to enter  3,6,9... and so on.

So here my issue is if I type a 2 in spinner field text box. GXT widget accept that value.

Posible solutions:

1. Is there any predefined properties of spinnerfield that i forget to set it?
2. Is there any predefined validator for this?
3. Can I set text box of spinner field read only by css so user cannot focus on text box but still change a value.
4. If none of above how to achieve manually?

Answer (score 0):

1. i've searched a bit in the different classes and I don't see either a precise method which would set what you want.
2. Don't know about one, and even with one, a validator doesn't change the value in the input field, but maybe it's enough for your needs.
3. You can disable the text input by calling setEditable(boolean) on the spinnerfield (testSpinner.setEditable(false);)
4. Maybe you could search around the IntegerPropertyEditor, I haven't tried but as long as a new Spinner is like this:

```
SpinnerField<Integer> testSpinner = new SpinnerField<Integer>(new NumberPropertyEditor.IntegerPropertyEditor());
```

you can seen that there is another Constructor for IntegerPropertyEditor, which takes a "NumberFormat" param, but there is no NumberFormart() constructor, so I'm not sure about how you create your own one, but that could be an idea (to format numbers in the input to be a multiple of the increment).

The last option would be that Sencha forgot this possibility and that you should report this as a "bug" on the forum ?

Hope to have helped a bit, good luck :).